# Find position of check box in list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom adapter for a list view. The row view is a check box. I have used `setOnClickListener()` to handle when the user clicks the check box. What I am wondering is if there is a way for me to know the position of the check box in the list view when it is clicked.

Here is the code for my adapter if it helps.

```
private class TagAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    public TagAdapter(ArrayList<Tag> items) 
    {
        mTagList = items;
    }
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return mTagList.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return mTagList.get(position);
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View V = convertView;

        if(V == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            V = vi.inflate(R.layout.tag, null);
        }

        Tag t = (Tag) mTagList.get(position);
        TextView tagName = (TextView)V.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)V.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        cb.setChecked(t.isSelected());
        cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() //the add tag button "+"
        {
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {

            }

       });

        tagName.setText(t.getTagName());
        return V;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the check box use the `setTag` method to add any data you want. You can even store the list item as the tag.

Comment: Thanks not sure if that should have been obvious but after a long time searching I had not found a solution. Thank you very much!